# Show that $(3,1)$, $(-2,-1)$, and $(4,3)$ generate the additive group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $(3,1)$, $(-2,-1)$, and $(4,3)$ generate the additive group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

I need your help.

Answer (score 2):

As for vector spaces, to show that a given set $S$ generates the group, it suffices to show that the elements of a known generating set can be expressed in term of $S$. In this case you can take the standard generators $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ and express them as integer combinations of the vectors given.

While a *general* method to find such an expression may be somewhat harder to formulate, you can get around here by some simple trial and error. Try to assemble "small" elements, for instance the sum of the first two given elements looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(4,3)-2*(2,1) = (0,1)$ and $(3,1)-(2,1) = (1,0)$. Thus the standard generators of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ are included in the set generated by your elements, so every element is.